# dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'domainType' of non-nullable type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, html.dropdownlistfor

I was wondering if someone could help me understand why the POST action below (SelectDomain) is always passed a null value. The Post method should be passed an enum type ( Demo, Client, Dev } using a dropdown menu but this is currently not the case.

In my controller I have the following lines:

```
public enum DomainCategories { Demo, Client, Dev };

public ActionResult SelectDomain()
{
    SetViewBagDomainType(DomainCategories.Client);
    return View();
}

private void SetViewBagDomainType(DomainCategories domainCategories)
{
    IEnumerable<DomainCategories> values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DomainCategories)).Cast<DomainCategories>();

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =
        from value in values
        select new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = value.ToString(),
            Value = value.ToString(),
            Selected = value == domainCategories,
        };

    ViewBag.WebsiteType = items;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectDomain(DomainCategories domainType)
{
    ViewBag.messageString = domainType.ToString() +
                            " val = " + (int)domainType;
    myWebsite.subdomain = domainType.ToString();
    createWebsite();
    return View(myWebsite);
}
```

In the view I have the following:

```
@model Installer.Models.Website
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SelectCategory";
}

<h2>Select Category</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        Subdomain: 
        @Html.DropDownList("WebsiteType")
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

The full exception is:
[ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'domainType' of non-nullable type 'Installer.Controllers.WebsitesController+DomainCategories' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SelectDomain(DomainCategories)' in 'Installer.Controllers.WebsitesController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code when posting. There's really no need for it to look that messy. And *where* do you get that error? Presumably it's an exception - what does the stack trace look like?

Comment: No problem Jon. I pressed ctrl K and thought It took care of it.

Comment: No, that just indents or outdents once. *Always* look at the preview before you post. Read through your question to make sure it's as clear as you want it to be, and laid out as you want it to be.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will do in the future. Is the current question clear to you?

Comment: No, as you still haven't provided the details of the exception - or what the content of your POST request is.

Comment: The POST method is passed one of DomainCategories values declared earlier. I am following this tutorial and I think I did everything correctly [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: I suggest you write a short console app - or use something like [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) so you can see *exactly* what you're posting. It sounds like the value isn't making it to the method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Html.DropDownList("WebsiteType")` renders the following html

```
<select id="WebsiteType" name="WebsiteType">
  <option value="Demo">Demo</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="Client">Client</option>
  <option value="Dev">Dev</option>
</select>
```

`public ActionResult SelectDomain(DomainCategories domainType)`

is expecting an parameter called `domainType`, but the browser is sending `WebsiteType`.

You can fix this by either changing your parameter name

`public ActionResult Index(DomainCategories websiteType)`

Or updating your controller to set ViewBag name to domainType, and updating the view to match this.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am such an amateur ha